# How to chain KBuild Makefiles properly to build subfolders inside kernel module

Tags: c, makefile, build, linux-kernel, kbuild

I have a kernel module (often compiled using CONFIG_MYMODULE=m) which is set-up like the following:

```
mymodule/Makefile
../foo/Makefile
../foo/component1/Makefile
../foo/component2/Makefile
```

Currently what's being used is:

**mymodule/Makefile:**

```
mymodule-y += mod1file.o mod2file.o mod3file.o #etc
include ../foo/Makefile
mymodule-y += $(FOO_FILES)
obj-$(CONFIG_MYMODULE) += mymodule.o
```

**../foo/Makefile:**

```
include component1/Makefile
include component2/Makefile
```

and inside each component folder I have:

**../foo/component1/Makefile**

```
FOO_FILES += foo1file.o foo2file.o foo3file.o #etc
```

---

This definitely doesn't appear to be the proper way of going about this, as everything is included directly into the mymodule/Makefile and thus can't set folder-specific gcc flags.

What is the proper way of organizing this while still building everything into a **single kernel module**? I've read the kbuild/modules.txt documentation, but I haven't seen anything which relates directly, and I can't quite figure out how to go about this or if it's indeed possible.

Thanks

---

I've tried the following, but I get the following error:

> **"ld: cannot find foo: File format not recognized"**

**mymodule/Makefile:**

```
mymodule-y += mod1file.o mod2file.o mod3file.o #etc
mymodule-y += ../foo/
obj-$(CONFIG_MYMODULE) += mymodule.o
```

**../foo/Makefile**

```
ccflags-y := -I$(src)/component1/ -I$(src)/component2/
foo-y := foo1file.o foo2file.o foo3file.o
foo-y += component1
foo-y += component2
```

**../foo/component1/Makefile**

```
component1-y := component1file.o component1file.o
```

**../foo/component2/Makefile**

```
component2-y := component2file.o component2file.o
```

If I change this to instead use obj-y += ../foo rather than mymodule-y += ../foo it at least enters the folder, but doesn't seem to attempt to complile, and I want this to be all a part of a single kernel module.

Comment: You can add folders to the list of objects. Check any *folder/Makefile* in the sources.

Comment: @AndyShevchenko: I've tried looking at a bunch of them already, but they don't appear to handle multiple chaining of Makefiles into the same kernel module.  Isn't that what I"m attempting to do at the bottom with foo-y += ../foo/? If I do something like "obj-y += ../foo/" work with compiling into the mymodule kernel module? I'm still a bit confused. Do you have a good example I can look at? Thanks!

Comment: `obj-[ym]` is a global space of separate units. You need to use module namespace for that.

Comment: From my example, would that me mymodule-y += ../foo/ or would it be something like foo-y += ../foo ?


And then what would I do inside my foo/Makefile? Would that be mymodule-y += component1 or would I use a separate module namespace?

Answer (score 1):

This doesn't seem too difficult.

**mymodule/Makefile:**

```
...
include ../foo/Makefile
...
# whatever rules use the folder-specific flags:
foo:
    gcc blah blah $(FOLDERFLAGS) blah
```

**../foo/component1/Makefile:**

```
FOLDER_FILES := foo1file.o foo2file.o foo3file.o #etc
$(FOLDER_FILES): FOLDER_FLAGS=folder_1_flag
FOO_FILES += FOLDER_FILES
```

**../foo/component2/Makefile:**

```
FOLDER_FILES := foo20file.o foo21file.o foo22file.o #etc
$(FOLDER_FILES): FOLDER_FLAGS=folder_2_flag
FOO_FILES += FOLDER_FILES
```

Is that sufficient for your purposes?

Comment: Somewhat, but it doesn't make use of the kbuild objects at all. I don't really want to call gcc directly, and  I don't have any other targets in mymodule/Makefile.

Comment: @Jordan: I'm not familiar with kbuild; how do you pass gcc flags to it?

Comment: It seems you don't do it directly:

http://lxr.free-electrons.com/source/Documentation/kbuild/makefiles.txt

Comment: Section 3.2 should explain some of it. I don't quite understand it fully myself.

Comment: @Jordan: I'm not going to sift through that huge document in the hopes of guessing correctly how to use a tool I don't have to experiment with. If your real question is how to use kbuild, I can't help you.

Comment: Yep, that's fair thanks. My question was more directed specifically at how to do this with kbuild, I wouldn't ask anyone who isn't familiar with it. Cheers

Answer (score 0):

You can get parent directories working using `subdir-` and `extra-y` but is just an overhead and still ccflags per directory wouldn't work. Perhaps the proper way would be to have components as sub-modules, with dependency to mymodule.

I would keep the module build in the top directory `mymodule/Makefile`, is easy to build multiple modules from one directory but I found nothing about one module from multiple objects in subdirectories (maybe a *keep a clean design* policy, or just was easier this way).

`obj-m` define the list of kernel modules to build (only one in the example below: `hello.ko`, is named `hello.o` but will output `hello.ko`)

`hello-objs` define the list of compiled *objects* to link to get `hello.ko`, by using the same *name*: `hello`.

Being a Makefile is easy to link objects conditionally (see `CONFIG_HELLO_COMPONENT1`)

Eventually if there are many objects per component and we want to keep the top Makefile clean we can still use `include` but just to *conditionally* add objects to `hello-objs` and flags to `ccflags-y` (or whatever variable needed, just not `obj-*`).

`CFLAGS_$*.o` (see below) can be used to set per object cflags, but it doesn't honour the path, so objects with the same name in different directories will have the same flags.

`mymodule/Makefile`:

```
ifeq ($(CONFIG_HELLO_COMPONENT1), y)
 ccflags-y += -I$(src)/foo/component1 -DCONFIG_HELLO_COMPONENT1
endif
ccflags-y += -I$(src)/foo/component2

obj-m += hello.o

CFLAGS_component2.o += -DTEST_CFLAGS

hello-objs = hello-1.o
ifeq ($(CONFIG_HELLO_COMPONENT1), y)
 hello-objs += foo/component1/component1.o
endif
hello-objs += foo/component2/component2.o

all:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) modules

clean:
    make -C /lib/modules/$(shell uname -r)/build M=$(PWD) clean
```

For completeness below all the files, should build and work, with `make` or `make CONFIG_HELLO_COMPONENT1=y`.

`mymodule/hello-1.c`:

```
#include <linux/module.h>
#include <linux/kernel.h>
#include <linux/init.h>
#ifdef CONFIG_HELLO_COMPONENT1
#include <component1.h>
#endif
#include <component2.h>
static int __init init_hello(void) {
#ifdef CONFIG_HELLO_COMPONENT1
    component1();
#endif
    component2();
    printk(KERN_INFO "Hello world 1.\n");
    return 0;
}
static void __exit cleanup_hello(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "Goodbye world 1.\n");
}
module_init(init_hello);
module_exit(cleanup_hello);
```

`mymodule/foo/component2/component2.h`:

```
#ifndef COMPONENT2_H
#define COMPONENT2_H
void component2(void);
#endif
```

`mymodule/foo/component2/component2.c`:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
void component2(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "component2\n");
}
```

`mymodule/foo/component1/component1.h`:

```
#ifndef COMPONENT1_H
#define COMPONENT1_H
void component1(void);
#endif
```

`mymodule/foo/component1/component1.c`:

```
#include <linux/kernel.h>
void component1(void) {
    printk(KERN_INFO "component1\n");
}
```